# Send a sendgrid legacy template

Tags: c#, sendgrid

I am using C#, 4.7.1 FW, and the SendGrid nuget.

I have been in contact with SG support and so far have not yet been directed to or figured out how to send a template. I have tried to use the native MailMessage, and also the SendGridMessage.

I have my template id specified and I keep running into problems where the email fails and I am told "Substitutions may not be used with dynamic templating"

Here is the latest snippet I am bashing my head against a brick wall over:

```
var apiKey = "snip";
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var from = new EmailAddress("from@domain.com", "display name");
        var subject = "Sending an email template";
        var to = new EmailAddress("me@domain.com", "To Name");
        var plainTextContent = "";
        var htmlContent = ""; // I read htmlContent needs to be blank?
        var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmail(from, to, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent);
        Personalization p = new Personalization
        {
            Substitutions = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        };
        p.Substitutions.Add("[eventname]", "test event"); // my template has 3 subs, this is one of them
        p.Tos = new List<EmailAddress>();
        p.Tos.Add(to);
        msg.Personalizations.Add(p);
        msg.SetTemplateId("snip");
        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        var stringResponse = response.Body.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Response:

{"errors":[{"message":"Substitutions may not be used with dynamic templating","field":"personalizations.1.substitutions","help":"http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.personalizations.substitutions"}]}

I am this close to just reverting all of this to building my own HTML template and storing that in a database, pulling it and replacing the placeholders like [eventname] with values. This shouldn't be this hard.

Comment: Where in your code do you comply with the first error message, that the personalizations object's To array is populated with at least one mail address?

Comment: edited code - and the error messages, just the one error now regarding subs may not be used with dynamic templating @CaiusJard

Comment: Is this relevant to the second error message? https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/712 (and its follow up release announcement https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/716 )

Comment: (I never used this part of sendgrid, just helping you with a bit of cardboard analysing. SG seems to be stating that substitutions and dynamic templating are different, and your message has a dynamic template, so filling it out using subs isn't the way to go- 10 months ago the c# library couldn't fill out a dyn template but now it can a) are you up to date and b) check the second link for clues as to how, or switch your message to use subs instead of a dyn template (can't advise how right now, because I don't know, and the SG code I have for subs is at work))